# Foundation of mathematics and functions

Tags: set-theory, foundations

I am interested in the foundations of mathematics. I know some of the ideas of set theory, especially ZFC. One way to define a function $f$ in such theory is to take $E$ and $F$ two sets, $G \in\mathcal{P}(E \times F)$ and set $f = (E,F,G)$ with some properties verified by $G$, mainly $f(x)=y \iff (x,y) \in G$.

I thought about the example of the following "function" $f = (\Omega,\overline{\mathbb{N}},G)$ where for all set $E$, $f(E) = \lvert E \rvert$. But I see two problems with this. First, we would need $\Omega$ to be the set of all sets, which does not exist. Second, $f(G) = +\infty$ and so $(G,+\infty) \in G$, which leads to self-reference of $G$.

However, the idea for defining this function seems pretty intuitive and "doable". Are there any theories where this function makes sense? I even imagined that some theory could have functions as its base objects, defined over all other possible object, and we would only need to focus on the objects we want for the domain. This would (I think) solve the "set of all sets" problem, but not the self-reference one, and I don't see how to build other objects (such as sets) from these base objects.

Comment: You have defined what is called a "class function". I presume by $|E|$ you don't mean the cardinality, but either the cardinality of a finite set, or the symbol $+\infty$. I personally don't see why you have $(G+\infty)\in G$, but these are good questions to work through when you are learning about elementary set theory. On that note, unfortunately, this means that the question is off-topic here, since MO is designed to be focused on questions that arise in original mathematics research (roughly: PhD level and above).

Comment: We could also take the example of $f = (\Omega,\{0,1\},G)$ such that $f(A) = 0$ if $A$ is finite, and $f(A) = 1$ if $A$ is infinite. $G$ is itself a set, and is clearly infinite, so $(G, 1) \in G$.

Comment: What is $\mathcal{P}(E,F)$? A function $G$ from $E$ to $F$ is an _element_ of the powerset of $E\times F$, so you have $G\in \mathcal{P}(E\times F)$, if $\mathcal{P}$ denotes powerset. What you are denoting $\overline{N}$ is usually denoted $\omega+1$, and it is the set $\{0,1,2,\ldots,\omega\}$, where $\omega = \{0,1,2,\ldots\}$, $n+1 = \{0,1,2,\ldots,n\}$, and $0=\emptyset$. The element you call $+\infty$ is $\omega$. By mixing normal mathematics notation for functions, and the formal set theory definition, you have run slightly aground. This needs to go down to Kuratowski ordered pairs.

Comment: To answer your question about where there are theories that makes sense, I would suggest looking at [NBG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory) for talking about proper classes. This is orthogonal to the issue of worrying about well-foundedness of $G$

Comment: You are right about the powerset, I wrote this too fast. As for $\omega$ (which I think is the first transfinite ordinal), I don't know much about this, but I think we can use $+\infty$ just like we do with measures which take values in $\overline{\mathbb{R}_+} = \mathbb{R}_+ \cup \{+\infty\}$. I will check the link you provided, thanks.

Comment: And to fix up a small error in what I wrote: in this context, it's better to say G is a subclass of $E\times F$, so $G \subset E\times F$, since the question is about a class function. If $E$ and $F$ are sets, the "element of the powerset..." version is a) meaningful and b) equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the conundrum is that if you take $\Omega$ to be a proper class (whose elements are sets), then $G$ is a subclass of the product class $\Omega \times \overline{\mathbb{N}}$ (however you wish to define the latter). Further, $G$ is a proper class, as, for instance, there is a surjective class function onto $\Omega$ (take the restriction to $G$ of the projection on the first component, $\Omega \times \overline{\mathbb{N}} \to \Omega$, and it's surjective as the function is claimed to be total). Then since elements of $\Omega$ are sets, elements of $G$ are sets. Thus $G$ cannot be in the domain of $G$, and so there is no "self-reference".